# How to grep an XML tag and get only the value inside the quotes after it?

Tags: linux, grep, xmllint

I'm trying to get these values from the XML format below: `USA GERMANY`

```
<country name="USA"  id="TEST1" password="123"   />
<country name="GERMANY" id="TEST2" password="456"  />
```

I was checking `xmllint` but I don't have `--xpath` installed and I just can't quite get the exact combination to get those values using `grep`.

Comment: `grep` is bad choice for such case

Comment: To reinforce the comment that `grep` is a bad choice: No matter what you do, it will totally fail as soon as the XML files get formatted bit differently, e.g. with line breaks. There are enough XML tools, or alternatives like `sgrep` available you don't need to rely on `grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
grep -P -o -e '(?<=name=").*?(?=")'
```